# Difficulty of switching from HTML only e-mail to Text only e-mail in .net C#?

Tags: c#

I am working with a consulting group on a program which currently uses a .net C# script to send e-mails in HTML format at regular intervals.

The e-mail itself aside from being in HTML format although the content is text with some 
 tags and contains less then a page of text.

I would like the consultant to change this to text format replacing the 
 tags with line feed/carriage returns. I have been told that this is a four hour job but that seems excessive to me.

When I look online at a page such as this http://www.mattvanandel.com/771/c-sending-an-email/ it would seem the change could be completed in less than 4 hours including recompiling the .net code into a DLL, testing and uploading the code to a server.

Not all developers are created equal, but assuming that the .Net developer is experienced enough to warrant a $250 per hour salary does this seem reasonable? If it is something less than 4 hours (i.e. more like 4 min) can someone tell me what might have to be done to make the modification. From what I can see its likely 2 lines of code that need to be modified (i.e. the body string and the IsBodyHtml statement). What else may I be missing?

Comment: Is this the only change you are asking for?

Comment: have you seen the html agility pack?

Comment: There's no correct answer to this question. It all comes down to trust. If you don't trust your "consultant" ($250 ph??? wtf?) get rid of him... otherwise let him get on with his job. There could be many factors at play here that might affect what he has told you. Voting to close.

Comment: Perhaps agree to the 4 hours and then spend 4 hours sitting with him while he does it. For $250/hr he should be able to code while you watch. That will help you to know if it is excessive or if there's a genuine reason, and could be 4 hours well spent.

Comment: As an aside I would edit your question to remove an biases you may be presenting towards consultants as this may put peoples backs ups without getting to the substance of the question - i.e. is this really a big change, and what if so why.

Comment: For $250ph, **I'll** do it in four minutes.  Paypal me $16.66.

Comment: @ste As a dev manager I worry about your team (lol)

Comment: @PreetSangha I would have delegated it to one of them with a 2 minute allowance anyway.  ;o)

Comment: @PreetSangha I understand the question is biased but its important for people to also see that when responding. I work with lots of consultants who do great work. I even believe the developers on their team are good. My gut feeling is that the scenario requires less than four hours and its the project manager (not the developer) who padded the (fixed) estimate.

But I'm not a C# professional so I need to reach out to others who are to get a feel for if I am being unreasonable. I got some great advice. Thanks for your comments and to everyone who participated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependant upon what kind testing would be required to verify that the system is stable after the change, then perhaps 4 hours may or may not be excessive.

For a simple looking change in a tightly coupled system may have massive implications and risk. On the other hand in a loosely coupled system, the risk should be minimal.

So the question is, why 4 hours. If it was me. I'd request a breakdown of what the 4 hours represents. You are after all the customer and if you need a cost breakdown I'd suggest you're within your purview to request it.

However I'd suggest that you ask in a non confrontational way (i.e. don't jump in with all guns blazing) as the there may well be serious implications that the developer knows about but you don't. Maybe just ask for a simple - 'what is involved in implementing this change'.

And don't feel you have to accept the first answer given, you should if you are dissatified, request further clarification from the developer.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the code is written - and on that we can only speculate currently.  It may be that they use a really complex 3rd party tool - in which case it might take four hours.

However, if it is done using `System.Net.Mail` then it could be as simple as setting the `IsBodyHtml`property on a `MailMessage` to `true`, which is a four-second job.

Answer (score 1):

Changing that 'IsBodyHtml' property would make it send text, but you would also need to modify the text to insert the line feeds - on static text this is not totally difficult, but you need to consider when a line feed is proper (what in the html has "block" layout and what is simple in-line styled).  Also you do not mention if the text is dynamic or static which adds complications if it IS dynamicly generated.

Time you pay for, but also knowlege.  I get someone else to fix things on my car, not because I can't, but because they are better and have the tools I might not have.

Just from a time spent perspective:

1. Get knowlege/use knowlege already present
2. Estimate time to communicate with you
3. Design the change
4. Code the change
5. Deploy the change
6. Test the change/functional test
7. Solicit feedback on the change/acceptance test (from you?)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one property "`IsBodyHtml`"  of `MailMessage` Class in .net to switch between Html/Text mail message type.

So you can check yourself, how big is the job excepting removing html tags and pumblishing the updated dll on server.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanics of switching the code itself is as simple as you say above, replacing the HTML body string with the new string and changing the IsBodyHtml property.  (Assuming the code uses the built in .NET Framework mailing components).

Remember though, that text based emails will remove all formatting, so you won't be able to have font colours, images, hyperlinks or anything else in the content except as plain text.

If you really want to cut the estimate down, get someone internal to edit the text and all the developer will have to do is switch 2 lines of code and then test/deploy.

I can't comment on the time required to test/deploy as that's entirely dependent on your system.